# Sequelize ORM - Auto-increment function not working for new user creation in database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, database-schema, auto-increment

> I use sequelize ORM. I have created a register route and controller to create new user. I created a new user with AVA test, but the auto-increment function isn't working properly. Despite being the fourth user created, this new user created with AVA test has an ID of 1 (The other three users were created using Sequelize seeders). I've checked the database schema and confirmed that the 'id' field is set to auto-increment. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

**Terminal output :**

```
npm test .../tests/register/registerTest.js

> test
> ava --require dotenv/...tests/register/registerTest.js


Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Users" ("uuid","username","email","password","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING "uuid","username","email","password","createdAt","updatedAt";
  ✔ RegisterNewUser function should create a new user and return a token (127ms)
    ℹ {
        token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N...Z_iVY8hjgsf9Ak',
        user: {
          createdAt: '2023-03-07T07:48:53.393Z',
          email: 'testuser@example.com',
          password: '$2b$10$kNeC1h7d0wX7WPQC3H.94OlpXveXVeaP7WaWEIGQN6VLypSVKoAE.',
          updatedAt: '2023-03-07T07:48:53.393Z',
          username: 'testuser',
          uuid: 'e33c6803-1c18-4d25-906f-2d6de8726d27',
        },
      }
  ─

  1 test passed
```

**PSQL Terminal output :**

```
database_test=# SELECT * FROM "Users";

 id |                 uuid                 | username |        email         |                           password                           |         createdAt          |         updatedAt          
----+--------------------------------------+----------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 15bf1cb7-8346-4140-8b36-ced76facb4d7 | johndoe  | johndoe@example.com  | $2b$10$1r.N1fS6ea82w9WgMZmdsevl/awhaWjSfWgwHzMXSWDNPdZlfS.bS | 2023-03-07 07:45:28.403+00 | 2023-03-07 07:45:28.403+00
  2 | af947f46-2991-43fd-aaec-dec95c40a729 | janedoe  | janedoe@example.com  | $2b$10$8H7ktluUZrr21SzE7Eo2MuegtmaCLMWjxHnQvg8LrlAD1uLI1BICm | 2023-03-07 07:45:28.412+00 | 2023-03-07 07:45:28.412+00
  3 | d2658a11-b088-4e86-a351-ee628c3a7cad | billdoe  | billdoe@example.com  | $2b$10$CBWz3iUSVot3nLqgSP3z4.ma2tiCp8SaPTKPRC3Z8fjHNMDJs.oIO | 2023-03-07 07:45:28.405+00 | 2023-03-07 07:45:28.405+00
  1 | e33c6803-1c18-4d25-906f-2d6de8726d27 | testuser | testuser@example.com | $2b$10$kNeC1h7d0wX7WPQC3H.94OlpXveXVeaP7WaWEIGQN6VLypSVKoAE. | 2023-03-07 07:48:53.393+00 | 2023-03-07 07:48:53.393+00

\d "Users"

database_test=# \d "Users"
                                       Table "public.Users"
  Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |               Default               
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------
 id        | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('"Users_id_seq"'::regclass)
 uuid      | uuid                     |           | not null | 
 username  | character varying(255)   |           | not null | 
 email     | character varying(255)   |           | not null | 
 password  | character varying(255)   |           | not null | 
 createdAt | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 updatedAt | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
```

models/user.js

```
'use strict';

// Import the bcrypt library for password hashing
const {
    Model
} = require('sequelize');

// Import the bcrypt library for password hashing
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Define a sequelize model for a User
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class User extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
...
                })
        }
    }
    User.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        uuid: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },

...

    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'User',
        // Add hooks to run code before or after certain events
        hooks: {
            // Hash the user's password before creating a new user
            beforeCreate: (User) => {
                const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                User.password = bcrypt.hashSync(User.password, salt);
            }
        },
    });
    return User;
};
```

migrations/20230223064615-create-user.js

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    },
...
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

seeder :

```
module.exports = {
    // The up function is responsible for defining the changes that should be applied to the database schema.
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        // Define an array of user objects with plaintext passwords.
        const users = [{
            id: 1,
                uuid: uuidv4(),
                username: 'johndoe',
                email: 'johndoe@example.com',
                password: 'password123'
            },
            {
            id: 2,
                uuid: uuidv4(),
                username: 'janedoe',
                email: 'janedoe@example.com',
                password: 'password456'
            },
....


    // The down function is responsible for undoing the changes made to the database schema by the up function.
    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        // Delete all users from the Users table using the bulkDelete function provided by Sequelize.
        return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show the seeder as well?

Comment: I have finally found my mistake. I manually defined the ID in the seeder, which is why the auto-increment ID function didn't work.

Comment: That's what I suspected

Answer (score 0):

I have manually defined the `id` field for a user in my seeder code. However, if I am using auto-incrementing IDs in my database, I should not be manually defining the IDs for each record.
When I insert a new record into a table with an auto-incrementing ID column, the database will automatically assign the next available ID to that record. By manually defining the ID in my seeder code, I am overriding this behavior and causing potential issues down the line.
To fix this issue, I have removed the `id` field from my seeder code, allowing the database to assign the ID automatically.  With this change, the database assigns a unique ID to each user record as it is inserted, ensuring that the IDs are unique and in sequence.